# How to make a test in Espresso that checks a string that contains HTML tag?

Tags: android, html, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am doing some UI testing on an android Fragment and I have the following string in my code:

```
textView.text = Html.fromHtml("$updateText <u>Change</u>?")
```

And in my test I have this code:

```
recoverPasswordAssert{

    checkTextIsVisible("Number format. Change?")
}
```

When I run the test this error happens:

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Number format. Change?"
```

I think it's missing the HTML tag from the fragment code, but how to get the tag in the Espresso test?

Comment: Did you try: "Number format. <u>Change?</u>" in your checkTextIsVisible() to see if it is looking for that instead? The actual text may be rendered different from the underlying ```String```.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Yes, I try but I received this error: `androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching:`

Answer (score 1):

```
val text = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.getString(R.string.<string_id>)
onView(withText(text)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

where `<string_id>` is from `strings.xml` in the following format:

```
<string name="some_string_key"><![CDATA[Example HTML text with <u>this</u> and <b>that</b>.]]></string>
```